# Need help correcting Access Violation with FFmpeg DLL

Tags: c++, dll, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use the FFmpeg dll's using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm getting a run time access violation when I call `avcodec_find_encoder`.  Here is the code:

```
// TestFFmpeg.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"
}

#define INBUF_SIZE 4096

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AVCodec *codec;

    const char *videoFilename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Videos\\Wildlife.wmv";

    av_register_all(); // This works; however, no parameters or return values.

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_WMV3);  // Run time Access Violation HERE
    if (!codec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message:

*Unhandled exception at 0x75C18B60 (msvcrt.dll) in TestFFmpeg.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000049.*

The stack trace is:

```
    msvcrt.dll!_strcmp()    Unknown
    avcodec-54.dll!6a56caac()   Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for avcodec-54.dll]    
>   TestFFmpeg.exe!wmain(int argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 23    C++
    TestFFmpeg.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 533 C
    TestFFmpeg.exe!wmainCRTStartup() Line 377   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

I'm guessing there's a problem with returning the `codec` pointer, but I'm new to C++ and have no idea how to correct it.  I tried the cdecl, stdcall, and fastcall calling conventions -- none corrected the issue.  I'm using the latest 32-bit DLL from Zeranoe.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I've called other functions in the DLL and they work.  For example, `avformat_open_input` works properly.  I can pass parameters and the function returns a successful return value (0) and populates the format context structure.  `av_find_stream_info` works as well.  I still can't figure out why `avcodec_find_decoder` creates an access violation.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I switched to avcodec_find_encoder_by_name, I had to switch to a string.  The new code runs without errors,  but always returns NULL (failure) even when I pass a valid codec name as a string.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: if you pass an invalid pointer to `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name` (e.g. `(char *)0x49`), what does the backtrace look like? Does it crash in the same `avcodec` location?

Comment: ` avcodec_find_encoder_by_name((char *)0x49)` runs without error and, correctly, returns a null pointer.

Comment: Oh dear...that's not a good sign. I think the DLL and your compiler must be in disagreement. I'd actually recommend building `libav` from source if that's what you need; it's not all *that* difficult and it should resolve your issues if you use the same compiler.

Comment: Can I build the DLL using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 even though it doesn't conform to C99?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17153/discussion-between-james-and-nneonneo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, fixed it.  I did two steps and I'm not sure which one worked (heh):

1. Added the '.lib' files as linker input dependencies
2. I picked up the Sept 7 build and made sure I have all the same build-date for the dll's, libraries, and include files.

Everything appears to work fine now.

Comment: This does not elaborate the real reason for the fix, seems MSVC had a bug in itself this seems to be fixed in 2012 and above. More Info: http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Linking-to-FFmpeg-with-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b